# Explanation about filter loop_shop_per_page with woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I needed to find a way to custom my pagination for a shop page only.
So I found this :

```
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', 'new_loop_shop_per_page', 20 );

function new_loop_shop_per_page( $cols ) {
   // $cols contains the current number of products per page based on the value stored on Options -> Reading
   // Return the number of products you wanna show per page.
   $cols = 9;
   return $cols;
}
```

This worked very well.
But I can't find where the hook/action is in all my woocommerce files.
I know this filter applies on something, but can't guess where.
Impossible to find an explanation on the web.

Does someone knows what it's about ?

Comment: Did you search the woocommerce plugin also ( not only your plugin/theme files ) ? It should be here : `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-query.php`

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer @AnatoliiBivol ! You're absolutly right !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comment : one must also search the woocommerce plugin also ( not only your plugin/theme files ).

`loop_shop_per_page` filter should be called here : `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-query.php`

Comment: Yup, I tried to look in these files but didn't find it. I'm starting/trying to get familiar with wordpress/woocommerce :).
Now I get it !